# Matlab: First derivative edge detection, about gradients

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection, sobel

I'm writing a program that asks the user to choose between ***Prewitt*** and ***Sobel*** image filters to detect edges of objects of an image. I must use their filter templates, not the `edge` function. The user also tells if he wants to detect 'horizontal', 'vertical' or 'diagonal' edges. My problem is theoretical rather than about programming.

In my notes i've got that to compute the magnitude of the gradient at each pixel, it is often approximated as `sqrt(Gx^2 + Gy^2)` where `Gx` would be the vertical derivative and `Gy` the horizontal derivative. But what is the value of `Gx` if I only calculate the horizontal edges? And the value of `Gy` if I'm only looking for the vertical edges?

I can't guess it by myself.

Comment: In case you are more familiar with mathematics: The first one measures the magnitude of the [total derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), wheras the second one measures only the [partial derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) `d/dx` and `d/dy`. I'm not really sure what else you are asking. Your question "*But what is the value of `Gx` if I only calculate the horizontal edges?*" translates to: "*What is the value of `Gx` if I only calculate `Gy`*", which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite simple.  What you are concerned about is performing an image filtering with masks, where each mask is a derivative filter.  With this approach, knedlsepp is correct in that doing it this way would only find the partial derivatives with respect to a given direction.  You would specify one mask to detect the horizontal and another for the vertical edges.

`Gx` stands for the **vertical** edge response by using a vertical derivative filter and `Gy` stands for the **horizontal** edge response by using a horizontal derivative filter.  To get the responses, you would take your image and filter it by 2D convolution with any of the masks.

Next, you would **combine** both of the responses together to get the overall magnitude response.  However, `edge` performs a lot of noise cleanup under the hood and also performs a thresholding to get the final response.  Simply computing the magnitude is not the full story of what `edge` does.

In any case, for detecting horizontal edges, the Prewitt mask looks like so:

```
Gy_prewitt = 

-1    -1   -1
 0     0    0
 1     1    1
```

Performing a filtering with the above mask finds the horizontal edge response, or `Gy`.

For finding the vertical edge response or `Gx`, you simply **transpose** the above mask and find the filter response, so:

```
Gx_prewitt =

     -1     0    1
     -1     0    1
     -1     0    1
```

The Sobel mask is slightly different than the Prewitt mask.  There is more exaggeration on the central row of the mask (for the vertical) or column (for the horizontal) of the mask and is weighted by twice as much.  The horizontal mask is:

```
Gy_sobel =

-1   -2   -1
 0    0    0
 1    2    1
```

Similarly, the vertical mask for the Sobel is defined as:

```
Gx_sobel =

 -1     0    1
 -2     0    2
 -1     0    1
```

What is important to note is that the total sum of all coefficients in the mask **equals to zero**, and is actually a property of any edge detection mask seen in practice.

Now, to determine the overall edge response, you would take the filtering responses for each of the horizontal, `Gy`, and vertical `Gx`, and apply the magnitude operation per corresponding pixel:

```
out = sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2);
```

---

If you want a more intuitive explanation as to why the Sobel mask is slightly different than the Prewitt, I encourage you to take a look at this post.  It provides a very good explanation as well as a good diagram on how to implement the filtering operation yourself if you can't use built-in convolution methods:

http://blog.saush.com/2011/04/20/edge-detection-with-the-sobel-operator-in-ruby/

Here's the diagram:

[image]

Basically, for each pixel you want to filter in your image, extract a 3 x 3 neighbourhood and perform a weighted sum between those pixels in the neighbourhood and the filter you want.  In this case, this would be the Sobel vertical edge detector.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's very complete and helpful but there's something I still don't know. I guess that if I only want to calculate the vertical edges I only need to calculate `Gx` and I won't need to apply the formula `sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2)` to determine the overall edge response because it will be `Gx` directly. The same for `Gy` and the horizontal edges. Am I right?

Comment: @user2952272 - Correct.  If you just want the horizontal or vertical edge response, you need `Gx` or `Gy` only.  However, it's possible to have negative responses, and you probably want to visualize this as a grayscale image.  The only caveat I will enforce is to make sure you visualize `abs(Gx)` or `abs(Gy)`.  Other than that, you are correct.